# onPreExecute as preloader for webview in a fragment

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments, webview

I am trying to show a preloader before loading the complete page as webview but here is a small problem which I already made a preloader but it goes on and on and there is no end to it .

How can I tell the script to stop showing dialog when the page is loaded .

```
    public class EzFragment extends Fragment {

        public ProgressDialog pDialog;


        public EzFragment(){}

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            new getFeed().execute();

        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ez, container, false);
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

             String summary = "<html><head> <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" 
href=\"http://www.example.com/demo/android_connect/assets/style/jquery.fullPage.css\" /></head></html>";
             myWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);


            myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/demo/android_connect/get_ez_webmob.php");
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



            return rootView;
        }


    private class getFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {
      @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setTitle("Connect to Server");
            pDialog.setMessage("This process can take a few seconds to a few minutes, depending on your Internet Connection Speed.");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    }
```

**Is it possible to add webview to Document doInBackground in order to load the page in background ?!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell the script to stop showing dialog when the page is
>   loaded .

Use `onPageFinished` to dismiss `ProgressDialog` because `onPageFinished` method is called when page is fully loaded in WebView :

```
 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        //.....
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("mytag","Page Loading Finished!");
            super.onPageFinished(myWebView, url);
            // dismiss ProgressDialog here
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks , but where should I add this code ?! before the end of my class ?!

Comment: @MacTaylor: after `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
` line

Comment: thanks   , there is a small problem to this method , and the moment page load is began , the preloader goes away ! Do you think adding webview to doInBackground is not a better move ?

Comment: @MacTaylor: `WebView` always run on main ui thread but `doInBackground` run in background on other thread so it's not possible to load and access any ui elements from `doInBackground`. and no need to use `AsyncTask` for showing `ProgressDialog` just show ProgressDialog before `WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);` line

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

*Stop the dialog in postexecute..*